# Trying to get property of non-object laravel bogardo/mailgun/src/http/response

Tags: php, laravel, package, mailgun

This error appears when I try to send email with mailgun package for laravel (bogardo/mailgun).

Route:

```
Route::post('mail-list/send/{type}/{id}', ['uses' => 'MailingList\MailingListController@sendSiteNews', 'as' => 'mail-list.send']);
```

Controller MailingListController

```
use Bogardo\Mailgun\Mail\Message;
use Mailgun;
```

Controller method:

```
public function sendSiteNews($type, $id) {
    $data = [];
    Mailgun::send('email.batch-news', $data, function (Message $message) {
        $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
    });
];
```

At first I've tried batch sending. Result was the same. After that I've tried to send simple message like above.

view email.batch-news contains only text with h1 tag.

Error message:

ErrorException in Response.php line 35:
Trying to get property of non-object

```
in Response.php line 35
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'D:\\wamp\\www\\asiacrochet\\vendor\\bogardo\\mailgun\\src\\Http\\Response.php', 35, array('response' => object(stdClass))) in Response.php line 35
at Response->__construct(object(stdClass)) in Mailer.php line 68
at Mailer->send('email.batch-news', array(), object(Closure)) in Service.php line 59
at Service->send('email.batch-news', array(), object(Closure)) in Facade.php line 221
at Facade::__callStatic('send', array('email.batch-news', array(), object(Closure))) in MailingListController.php line 67
at MailingListController->sendSiteNews('Lesson', '10')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(MailingListController), 'sendSiteNews'), array('Lesson', '10')) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('sendSiteNews', array('Lesson', '10')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(MailingListController), 'sendSiteNews') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 160
at Route->run() in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in HasRole.php line 24
at HasRole->handle(object(Request), object(Closure), 'administrator') in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 43
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 47
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

That is method of package:

```
public function __construct(stdClass $response)
    {dd($response->http_response_body);
        $this->status = $response->http_response_code;
        $this->message = $response->http_response_body->message;
        $this->id = property_exists($response->http_response_body, 'id') ? $response->http_response_body->id : '';
        $this->data = null;
    }

dd($response->http_response_body);
```

gives only that string value "Mailgun Magnificent API".

So that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your send-domain "email.batch-news". If this is incorrect mailgun, does identify the API method you are calling.

Comment: Yes, it was my fault in mailgun info. I've spent hours to find this problem.